# Using Derelict3 under DMD2 (D)

Tags: opengl, sdl, d

I've been using D for around a month now after using other languages such as C++ and Java. I've been wanting to move my simple game platform from Java to D, and I'd like to use the Derelict3 library to do so. I've compiled the github repository located here https://github.com/aldacron/Derelict3

Running Linux, if that helps.

I've placed my .a files in **/usr/lib/..** and I've placed my .d files (The import folder from the Derelict root directory) in **/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/dmd/druntime/import**

My code is as follows:

```
import std.stdio;

import derelict.opengl3.gl3;
import derelict.glfw3.glfw3;

pragma(lib, "/usr/lib/libDerelictUtil.a");
pragma(lib, "/usr/lib/libDerelictGL3.a");
pragma(lib, "/usr/lib/libDerelictGLFW3.a");

void main() {
    DerelictGL3.load();
    writeln("This is a line");
}
```

this is based on other questions that were answered on stackoverflow and some topics from the dlang.org forums, but the terminal spits this out at me when I'm compiling:

```
kevin@kevin-Latitude-D620:~$ dmd main.d
/usr/include/D/Derelict/libDerelictGL3.a(gl3.o): In function `_D8derelict7opengl33gl318_sharedStaticDtor2FZv':
../import/derelict/opengl3/gl3.d:(.text._D8derelict7opengl33gl318_sharedStaticDtor2FZv+0x4): undefined reference to `_D8derelict4util6loader15SharedLibLoader19isAutoUnloadEnabledOFNdZb'
/usr/include/D/Derelict/libDerelictGL3.a(gl3_d1_649.o):(.data+0x38): undefined reference to `_D8derelict4util6loader15SharedLibLoader7__ClassZ'
/usr/include/D/Derelict/libDerelictGL3.a(gl3_d1_649.o):(.rodata+0x4418): undefined reference to `_D8derelict4util6loader15SharedLibLoader4loadMFZv'
(MORE of the above)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
--- errorlevel 1
```

Comment: Don't know about your actual problem, but here is one important point. Try not to use absolute paths to libraries. On other machine than yours this code will cause compilation error if there are no libraries at the specified path. Use compiler flags or build system to manage library dependencies.

Comment: I think your `libDerelictUtil.a` is the Derelict2 Version.

Comment: It's not I downloaded it straight from the Derelict3 repo.

Comment: Spare yourself the lib trouble and just compile your game main.d with rdmd.

Comment: Compiling with rdmd gives me this error(I got the programs to compile with dmd but when I run them it gives the same error)

Should add I got the library installed on windows so I'm using that now

C:\Documents and Settings\Kevin Kowalczyk\My Documents>rdmd main.d
derelict.util.exception.SharedLibLoadException@C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\d
runtime\import\derelict\util\exception.d(38): Failed to load one or more shared
libraries:
        SDL2.dll - The specified module could not be found.
----------------
41284C
4126D7
40587C
405AE8
405A9F
4059E1
40201A
4061FA
405E1B
41ABD9
----------------

Comment: Self-explanatory. It can't find the SDL dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*ld*, the linker maintains a list of unresolved symbols as it moves first to last through the libraries to link, trying to reduce its list of unresolveds. This means that any dependencies should be listed **after** the code which depends on them. So try rearranging your pragma(libs...) like this:

```
pragma(lib, "DerelictGL3"); 
pragma(lib, "DerelictGLFW3"); 
pragma(lib, "DerelictUtil"); 
pragma(lib, "dl");
```